# Accessing linux terminal in web page in java web appliaction

Tags: java, linux

I have a Red hat linux server where my java/j2ee web application running , i want to  access the terminal of that server on web page of my web application. How can i  access it what approach would be good . I saw application on web that what exactly i  want but i don't know in what techonology it is been developed.
below is the link

```
http://services-7ed4e2dc-90f2-4c15-aef4-019924f2356d.runnablecodesnippets.com/static/term.html
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your exact intentions are but you could be opening up a major attack vector on your site if you are not careful. Why not just open an SSH connection to your server... Not through your site?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple memo on the webpage and in your code you can use a system call to do that, using [Apache Commons Exec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/) would help.

But, like @scunliffe said it can be **very dangerous**, avoid doing that.

You'd be taking something like [SQL Injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) to a whole new level.

If you want a way to control your server you have many other ways to do that, like SSH.